# Word wrap in Firefox 2.0

Tags: css, firefox, word-wrap, firefox2

Word-wrap is not working in FF 2.0. I know FF above 2.0 supports this word-wrap. But I want to know is there any alternatives do fix this issue for FF2.0. It works fine with all IE versions.

```
.wrapgridtext 
{
    word-break : break-all;
    max-width : 0;
    word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

this class is applied to the "td" in a table where it has width as 130px.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is it even that important to support FF2?  I'd think most FF users are tech-savvy, and keep their browsers updated (unlike, say, IE users)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at an old post of mine at

http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/55677

and see if this helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `overflow: hidden;`

That won't break the word, but it will keep the long line from breaking your site layout.

Answer (score 0):

word-wrap is NOT supported in FF2 and isn't even in the CSS2.1 spec. It's a CSS3 property.